# Difference between selenium and capybara at Ruby on rails Testing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, capybara, ui-automation

> Selenium - Testing Framework
>   Capybara - Ruby Integration Testing Tool

Could anyone explain, what is the actual difference Selenium and Capybara in terms of Ruby on Rails automation testing?

Answer (score 2):

In the simplest terms, the responsibilities of Capybara are

- To provide you with a DSL, with which you can express your browser interactions
- To translate that DSL to something its drivers understand
- To integrate with different testing frameworks/libraries (like rspec)

Selenium (as far as the Ruby world is concerned) is just a driver for Capybara. Its responsibilities are:

- To understand its own API for browser integrations (which is still high level, but not as high level as Capybara's DSL)
- To actually interact with the browser, based on the instructions given

Comment: Selenium doesn't interact directly with the browser. It either interacts with the browser driver or one or more intermediary nodes/servers which in turn interact with a browser driver. Also I would quibble that Selenium uses an API, not a DSL. Capybara has a DSL.

Comment: @titusfortner in the context of two moving parts - Capybara and Selenium, that is accurate. As for the remark ... OK, updated.

Answer (score 1):

In context of ruby integration specs,

capybara is the testing framework and selenium is one of its drivers (runs your tests in firefox). You can use other drivers with capybara (which can run your tests in headless chrome or without a browser at all).